# create date interval from string php from Date Now

Tags: php

I want to create a date interval from a string from date now, here's an example.

If my string tag is "today", so the algorithm gets the date Now `(2014-05-20 12:00:00)` and  returns me this interval `[ '2014-05-20 12:00:00' , '2014-05-20 23:59:59']` 24 hours,

ie: from a string (today, tomorrow, this week) it returns the interval time from that tag depended on the date now. If that possible please give me the php functions to do that.

I check with `createFromDateString()` and `DatePeriod()`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

```
function render_interval($str, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $now = (new DateTime('now'))->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format($format);
    $end = (new DateTime($str))->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format($format);

    return [$now, $end];
}

var_dump(render_interval('today'));
var_dump(render_interval('tomorrow'));
var_dump(render_interval('next week'));
```